# How to call java application from C++

Tags: java

I wrote a code in java that adjust the system sound volume based on value supplied as command line argument. I would like to execute this code from my C++ application. What is the best way to do this...

Do I need to install the jdk on the deployment machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle a runtime with your software and then call this from within your program, however, the better solution would be to perform the function that the Java app does natively within your C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your Java application from C++ as you can run any other executable.

Run "java.exe" with your Java class name as a parameter, as you would do normally when executing Java applications from the command line:

```
java.exe MyClass myParamToJavaClass
```

Alternatively you can pack your class in an executable jar archive, in which case your command to run your Java application would look something like this

```
java.exe -jar MyJarr.jar myParamToJavaClass
```

Substitute the ".exe" by something else if you aren't running under Windows.

In the examples above i assume that "java.exe" is in a directory defined in your "path" environment variable, as it normally is.

You do not need to install JDK but a JRE needs to be present on the deployment machine.